# Swift 4: CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)' when using AVPlayerViewController Only

Tags: swift, debugging, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm trying to play a local video file and keep getting the following log:

**[framework] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)'**

My video file is in the project directory and also in the main bundle resources. I've tried multiple versions of the syntax to play the video. Here's the code I have for now in a test project:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "slipMovement", ofType: 
    "mp4") {
        let video = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        let videoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
        videoPlayer.player = video

        present(videoPlayer, animated: true, completion:  {
            video.play()
        })
    }
}
```

When I use a AVplayer and PlayerLayer, I don't get the 'null' messages. It only happens when I use AVPlayerViewController.

I'm fairly new to programming, any help would be very much appreciated as I just can't find a working solution online.

Comment: You can ignore this log. It’s a system log. Will not effect your player implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same problem when playing downloaded files from AWS S3.

I don't have an explanation for the meaning behind the error message.
But in my case it was because the file was not actually playable.

---

#### 1. Make sure the path is correct.

I did not use `Bundle`.
I put the file under the *Documents* directory and I used `FileManager` to set the path:

```
let documentsUrl: URL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let localFileName: String = "recording.mp4" 
let localFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(localFileName)

print("Playing \(localFileUrl.absoluteString)")
```

That would print something like this:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D8AF92BD-D736-4B86-9FF4-C60ABA6C741B/Documents/recording.mp4
```

#### 2. Make sure the file is actually playable.

For this, I wanted to check what the file is actually like when it's stored on the device.
It turned out that file was "corrupted" (ex. copy/download interrupted), so it really wasn't playable.

- Connect the iOS device to your Mac.
- From Xcode, go to *Window* > *Devices and Simulators*
- Look for your device from the *Connected* list on the left.
- Look for your app from the *Installed Apps* list.
- Click the gears on the bottom of the list.
- Select *Download Container..*

[image: download container]

- Download the *.xcappdata to a local directory
- Open the directory in Finder
- Right-click on the *.xcappdata, then select *Show Package Contents*
- It should show something like the image below
- Check the file's properties and try to play it

[image: appdata]

#### 3. Make sure the file format is actually supported by `AVPlayer`

To see the supported AVPlayer formats, use `print(AVURLAsset.audiovisualTypes())`.

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avurlasset/1386800-audiovisualtypes

---

Once the path, the file, and the format were all OK, and I was able to play it normally using `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerViewController`.

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: localFileUrl)
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.player = player
self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
    playerViewController.player!.play()
}
```